# jQuery wrapping all headers and below elements until the next header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to wrap the header including the elements below it until the next header into one div.

I'm thinking of looping through all headers and get all elements until the last element. But I don't know how to properly execute it.

```
<h3>
   Login
</h3>
<p>asdadadadasd</p>
<h3>
    Register
</h3>
<p><strong>asdsadasdasd</strong></p>
<h4>
    test
</h4>
<p>dasdad</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>as</p>
<p>das</p>
<p>da</p>
<p>sd</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>as</p>
<p>das</p>
<p>d</p>
<h4>
    another-under
</h4>
<p>asdas<br>
    das<br>
    da<br>
    sd<br>
    as<br>
    das<br>
    das<br>
    d<br>
    asd<br>
    asd<br>
    as<br>
    das<br>
    d<br>
    asd<br>
    as<br>
    das</p>
<h4>
    app-check-onrange
</h4>
<p><code>dasd</code></p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>as</p>
<p>das</p>
<p>das</p>
<p>d</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>as</p>
<p>das</p>
<p>d</p>
```

So the code above will be something like this

```
    <div>
       <h3>Login</h3>
       <p>...</p>
       ...othercontent
    </div>
     <div>
       <h3>Register</h3>
       <p>...</p>
       ...othercontent
    </div>
    <div>
       <h4>test</h4>
       <p>...</p>
       ...othercontent
    </div>
    <div>
       <h4>another-under</h4>
       <p>...</p>
       ...othercontent
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please include the HTML instead of an image?

Comment: I have replaced it with the actual code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nextUntil()` function:

```js
$('h3, h4').each(function(index, element) {
  $(this).nextUntil('h3, h4').addBack().wrapAll( "<div class='new' />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>
  Login
</h3>
<p>asdadadadasd</p>
<h3>
  Register
</h3>
<p><strong>asdsadasdasd</strong></p>
<h4>
  test
</h4>
<p>dasdad</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>as</p>
<p>das</p>
<p>da</p>
<p>sd</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>as</p>
<p>das</p>
<p>d</p>
<h4>
  another-under
</h4>
<p>asdas<br>
  das<br>
  da<br>
  sd<br>
  as<br>
  das<br>
  das<br>
  d<br>
  asd<br>
  asd<br>
  as<br>
  das<br>
  d<br>
  asd<br>
  as<br>
  das</p>
<h4>
  app-check-onrange
</h4>
<p><code>dasd</code></p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>as</p>
<p>das</p>
<p>das</p>
<p>d</p>
<p>asd</p>
<p>as</p>
<p>das</p>
<p>d</p>
```